# Redux - dispatch is not being called

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm wrapping my head around this and cannot figure out why it's not working.

I have a simple action:

```
export const GET_EXPENSE_LIST = "GET_EXPENSE_LIST"

export const getExpenseList = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        console.log('Action called')
        dispatch({ type: GET_EXPENSE_LIST, expenseList: []})
    }
}
```

And a reducer:

```
import { GET_EXPENSE_LIST } from "../actions/expenses"

const initialState = {
    expenseList = []
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("reducer called")
}
```

I'm calling the action from a component like so (if it matters):

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(expensesActions.getExpenseList())
  }, [dispatch]);
```

In my console I do see the "action called" but I don't see the "reducer called". Why the reducer is not being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add thunk middleware to the config of redux? In you action you use redux-thunk

Comment: Oh you're right I added redux-thunk but not to that specific reducer
Thank you very much!

Comment: Should I delete this question? Or I can accept your answer in a few mins